# count returns to zero in preg replace

Tags: php, mysql, regex

I am trying to pool some regular expressions from database and if at least in one preg-replace changes data I want to echo it and not insert it to db. As for now my code looks like that:

```
$expq = "SELECT `Expression` FROM `expressions` LIMIT 0, 30 ";
$expr=  mysqli_query($db, $expq);
$exp=  mysqli_fetch_array($expr);

foreach ($exp as $expression)
{
    // echo $expression;
    $replacement = "";
    $count = 0;
    $limit=1024;

    $message = preg_replace($expression, $replacement, $message,$limit,$count);
    echo "cu"." ".$count;
}

if ( $count>0)
{
    //do stuff
}else{
    //do somethin else
}
```

But if statement newer works. What do i miss? or is their a better method to do this?

Comment: On each loop iteration, you're setting `$count` to `0`. The condition `if ( $count>0)` will never be satisfied if you do that.

Comment: when you are not incrementing then how can you expect it should send > 0

Comment: He passed the count variable to the `preg_replace` function which counts the number of replaced occurencys. What is happening is that the replaces are not working at all. You have to check the expression and what you are trying to replace with. I recommend you to do some 'debug' echoing the `$expression` variable and see if it is an valid regular expression at all.

Comment: Sorry but expressions are working and I echod a count variable it does show the number of replacements. But if statement doesn't work.